# Is there a similar solution as Array#wrap for hashes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, interface, hashmap, type-safety

I use `Array.wrap(x)` all the time in order to ensure that Array methods actually exist on an object before calling them.

**What is the best way to similarly ensure a Hash?**

Example:

```
def ensure_hash(x)
  # TODO: this is what I'm looking for
end
values = [nil,1,[],{},'',:a,1.0]
values.all?{|x| ensure_hash(x).respond_to?(:keys) } # true
```

Comment: It seems like it's far easier to convert arbitrary things to arrays because you can simply add the `[]` around it. How would this even work for hash? what is the key, what is the val?

Comment: @maxpleaner I know, right. It makes it tricky. Any ideas?

Comment: What sort of inputs are you expecting? If you're actually being given "anything at all" when you're expecting a hash, then maybe you're just papering over the real problem.

Comment: _"I use Array.wrap(x) all the time"_ – could you give an (actual) example?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, I was thinking "anything at all". Maybe you're right and it would be better to just let it error and fix errors as they come up, since this transformation would probably have to either throw away or make up data to output a Hash. Though I could still see this being a viable strategy for handling `nil` values.

Comment: @Stefan I added an example.  The intent was to avoid `NoMethodError`'s

Comment: @NathanHanna that example looks quite contrived, what's your actual use case (or the one for `Array#wrap`)?

Comment: You might be able to `x.to_h` depending on what your real use case looks like. But honestly, letting `NoMethodError`s happen is probably better than quietly and cleverly do the wrong thing when you're handed the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4):

The best I've been able to come up with so far is:

```
Hash::try_convert(x) || {}
```

However, I would prefer something more elegant.

Comment: i can't imagine something more elegant than this, given the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr: In an app with proper error handling, there is no "easy, care-free" way to handle something that may or may not be hashy.

From a conceptual standpoint, the answer is *no*. There is no similar solution as `Array.wrap(x)` for hashes.

An array is a collection of values. Single values can be stored outside of arrays (e.g. `x = 42`) , so it's a straight-forward task to wrap a value in an array (`a = [42]`).

A hash is a collection of key-value pairs. In ruby, single key-value pairs can't exist outside of a hash. The only way to express a key-value pair is with a hash: `h = { v: 42 }`

Of course, there are a thousand ways to express a key-value pair as a single value. You could use an array `[k, v]` or a delimited string `"k:v" or some more obscure method.

But at that point, you're no longer wrapping, you're parsing. Parsing relies on properly formatted data and has multiple points of failure. No matter how you look at it, if you find yourself in a situation where you *may or may not have a hash*, that means you need to write a proper chunk of code for data validation and parsing (or refactor your upstream code so that you can always expect a hash).